# Getting an error "cannot find symbol" while trying to compile a Kotlin and Java mixed project with Gradle

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle

I'm working on a Java-Kotlin mixed project (not using android).
When I try to compile project, I get "cannot find symbol" error wherever I refer to Kotlin class from Java class.
I followed instructions in the [Kotlin documention](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html) and also tried solutions in other questions, but it doesn't work.

I've put all Java files in src/main/java, and all Kotlin files in src/main/kotlin.

Below is `build.gradle` I'm using.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
        classpath "com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:$shadowVersion"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
}

if (!project.getPlugins().hasPlugin('org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm')) {
    apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm'
}

if (!project.getPlugins().hasPlugin('com.github.johnrengelman.shadow')) {
    apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'
}

def properties = new Properties()
new File(project.projectDir, '../../gradle.properties').withInputStream() { properties.load(it) }

group = properties.getProperty('group')
version = properties.getProperty('version')
sourceCompatibility = properties.getProperty('sourceCompatibility')

compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'

sourceSets {
    main.kotlin.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/java'
}

tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = ['-Xjvm-default=compatibility']
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

jar {
    finalizedBy shadowJar
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':Compatibility')
    compile 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:' + properties.getProperty('kotlinVersion')
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:' + properties.getProperty('guavaVersion')
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:' + properties.getProperty('gsonVersion')
    compileOnly 'org.jetbrains:annotations:' + properties.getProperty('annotationsVersion')
}
```

`gradle.properties`:

```
group=foo.bar
version=1.0.0
sourceCompatibility=1.8
kotlinVersion=1.4.10
guavaVersion=29.0-jre
gsonVersion=2.8.6
annotationsVersion=20.0.0
```

Problematic code

Kotlin code

```
enum class TaskType {
    INFINITE, NORMAL, REVERSE
}
```

Error message (From Java source)

```
error: cannot find symbol
super(TaskType.REVERSE);
      ^
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please add the problematic code and the java file in question.

Comment: @code_mechanic added problematic code and the error message

Comment: make your enum public

Comment: are you able to use other kotlin classes/symbols?

Comment: Also check if kotlin code is being compiled or not, I think kotlin plugin is not applied.

Comment: @code_mechanic Kotlin code is compiled, and there are classes in the build/classes/kotlin directory

Comment: @Mr.AF Kotlin class is basically public if there is no access modifier.

Comment: @code_mechanic No, every single Kotlin class reference is making a cannot find symbol error.